# How many threads do we run in this code sample? Can anyone draw a flowchart of it?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self firstTest];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self secondTest];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self thirdTest];
}

- (void)firstTest {
    NSLog(@"=================1");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"=================2");
    });

    NSLog(@"=================3");
}

- (void)secondTest {
    NSLog(@"ViewWillAppear=============");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"=================4");

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0f];

            NSLog(@"=================5");
        });

        NSLog(@"=================6");
    });

    NSLog(@"==========Main Thread Blocked");
}

- (void)thirdTest {
    NSLog(@"ViewDidAppear=============");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"=================7");

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"=================8");
        });

        NSLog(@"=================9");
    });
}
```

Comment: It depends on many things. Queues are not the same thing as threads and may map in numerous ways. What is the actual goal of your question? (Also, please format the code; it's currently illegible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(...))` may be run on a worker thread managed by the global queue, so you're potentially looking at three threads, but it's also possible that the first dispatch to the global queue may finish before the second starts, so you may actually end up using two threads, but given that you dispatch synchronously in `secondTest`, you'll almost certainly use three threads.

So the main thread will run 1, 3, 2, 5, and 8, a worker thread invoked by the global queue in `secondTest` will run 4 and 6, and a worker thread in `thirdTest` will run 7 and 9.

---

For what it's worth, Xcode 8's updated activity tracing makes this sort of analysis a little easier. For example, I can replace the `NSLog` statements with `kdebug_signpost` statements:

```
#import <sys/kdebug_signpost.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_group_t group;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    kdebug_signpost_start(1, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    // create a group that will call notify block when three `dispatch_group_leave` calls happen
    // by having an alert show up when all three tests are done, I can terminate the instruments
    // session at the appropriate time

    self.group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_enter(self.group);
    dispatch_group_enter(self.group);
    dispatch_group_enter(self.group);

    dispatch_group_notify(self.group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertController *controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"Done" preferredStyle:(UIAlertControllerStyleAlert)];
        [controller addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:true completion:nil];
    });

    // now carry on doing the tests

    [self firstTest];

    kdebug_signpost_end(1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    kdebug_signpost_start(2, 0, 0, 0, 2);

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self secondTest];

    kdebug_signpost_end(2, 0, 0, 0, 2);
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    kdebug_signpost_start(3, 0, 0, 0, 3);

    [super viewDidAppear: animated];

    [self thirdTest];

    kdebug_signpost_end(3, 0, 0, 0, 3);
}

- (void)firstTest {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        kdebug_signpost_start(4, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        kdebug_signpost_end(4, 0, 0, 0, 1);

        dispatch_group_leave(self.group);
    });
}

- (void)secondTest {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        kdebug_signpost_start(5, 0, 0, 0, 2);

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            kdebug_signpost_start(6, 0, 0, 0, 2);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0f];
            kdebug_signpost_end(6, 0, 0, 0, 2);

            dispatch_group_leave(self.group);
        });

        kdebug_signpost_end(5, 0, 0, 0, 2);
    });
}

- (void)thirdTest {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        kdebug_signpost_start(7, 0, 0, 0, 3);

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            kdebug_signpost_start(8, 0, 0, 0, 3);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
            kdebug_signpost_end(8, 0, 0, 0, 3);

            dispatch_group_leave(self.group);
        });

        kdebug_signpost_end(7, 0, 0, 0, 3);
    });
}

@end
```

I use the first parameter to indicate the task I'm interested in tracing, and I use the fourth parameter to indicate the color in "system trace". I can then specify names to associate with these unique identifiers as outlined in [System Trace in Depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/411/) so that they show up as "regions" in the "Points of Interest" section. You can then use the "System Trace" tool in Instruments, and you can see what's going on. There's not perfect correlation between these named regions and their associated threads, but it makes it quite easy to verify yourself (e.g. <kbd>control</kbd>-click on one of the named `kdebug` regions on the bottom to filter the timeline for just that part of the app's operation; etc.).

[image]

There's no way I can give this its due in this short answer, but I might suggest watching that video, which shows you how to associate activities in your code to activity on threads, cpus, etc. It admittedly takes a little playing around with this tool to become familiar with it (e.g. filtering down to just the process in question, learning to identify your threads versus other threads that the OS creates, etc), but it can helpful in identifying blocked threads, etc.